# Why my link is not working when firefox browser window is not opened in full screen?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my html page, I have two links located on the top of the page:

```
<div id='my-link'>
    <a class="school" href="../school.html" target="_blank">School</a> 
    <a class="police" href="../police.html" target="_blank">Police</a> 
 </div>
```

(When mouse click on the link, the linked page is supposed to be opened in a new browser window.)

the **CSS**:

```
#my-link{
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 22%;
  width: 20%;
}

a.school{
  color: #6ffe11;
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;

  position: relative;
  left: 30.5%;
  margin-top:10px;

}


a.police{
  color: #6ffe11;
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;

  position: relative;
  left: 30.5%;

  margin-top:10px;
}

a.school:hover, a.police:hover
{
color: #2f8;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I tested on firefox 3.6.16, when I open the firefox browswer window with **full screen**, the links are working successfully ("school", "police" pages opened successfully,
CSS hover feature is also working).

**BUT**, if I open the browser window size **not in full screen**, the links are **not working at all**, the "school" and "police" pages are not open, 
the CSS hover feature is not working either. 
**The link texts are like plain texts on the page.** **WHY???**

Comment: I would have a guess it would be something to do with the positioning, but thats just a guess.

Comment: No, they are like plain texts as I mentioned. Not working at all when browser window is not in full screen mode.(firefox browser)

Comment: Do you have extensions like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullerscreen/ installed? Does this affect only these links and nothing else on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that something else on the page that's positioned is above it. Can't be certain without seeing your whole page code though.

Try adding a `z-index` to your `#my-link` div

-- edit --

Sorry, with the nice range of CSS properties you'd already used I assumed you would have heard of `z-index`.

Replace

```
#my-link{
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 22%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

with

```
#my-link{
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: 22%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Lots of info on `z-index` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index

-- edit --

**Why it works**

If x is horizontal and y is vertical, as on a graph, z is towards or away from you. Using a `z-index` will bring something towards you. You can overlap these properties as well.

Take this as an example. Copy it into Notepad (or similar), save it and take a look at the code to understand. Alter the z-index properties of each div in the `style` section to see how it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title>Z-Index Example</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
          div { width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000; }
          #one { position: absolute; z-index: 10; top: 10px; left: 10px; background: #666; }
          #two { position: absolute; z-index: 30; top: 30px; left: 30px; background: #999; }
          #three { position: absolute; z-index: 20; top: 50px; left: 50px; background: #CCC; }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="one">Furthest away</div>
        <div id="two">Nearest</div>
        <div id="three">In the middle</div>

      </body>

    </html>
```

Naturally in HTML, the elements later on in the code would overlay the things that appear earlier. Using positioning to move things will affect where they sit in the natural flow of the page and may be overlapped. That's how I guesses your problem when I saw your `fixed` property in your CSS as you'd taken the `div` out of the natural flow.

Comment: I do not get you. What is z-index, how to add it to #my-link ? could you please be more specific?

Comment: @ Scott ,thank you. It works now. Could you please explain to me the reason of the problem and why z-index helps?

Comment: @Mellon I've put a detailed but simple example in for you.